# Alternativas a Console.ReadLine(); que lea ints y strings

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa de prueba que detecta si la entrada es una letra o un número.
Quiero saber si hay una alternativa a `Console.Readline()` que pueda leer tanto ints como strings sin necesidad de la conversión de `Convert.ToInt32`
Lo usaré a futuro para poner un mensaje de error predeterminado si la entrada no es la esperada, en vez de que muestre un error por defecto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AplyDefaultError
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Strint(string x){
           Console.WriteLine("Esto es una letra")  ;  
        } 
        static void Strint(int x){
          Console.WriteLine("Esto es un numero") ; 
        } 
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Strint(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que tu quieres es saber si tu entrada es valida?

Comment: La consola siempre recibirá una serie de carácteres. No conozco si en .NET existe alguna función que haga lo que pides. Tampoco puedes adivinar qué tipo de dato quiso ingresar el usuario pero sí controlar qué debe ingresar.

Comment: La repuesta a tu pregunta es sencilla. No existe una alternativa que haga lo que dices. Qué hay de los otros tipos de datos? Una función que sólo tome `DateTime`? Una que tome sólo `bool`? una que tome `char`? una que tome `decimal`? una que tome `float`? una que tome `long`?

Comment: La informacion que no es relevante para la pregunta no va. lo tuyo es un comentario que no es para nada necesaria en la pregunta y la ensucia. Lo que tienes que hacer es usar console.ReadLine y parsear al dato que vos quieras. Podes usar int.TryParse.